# Trouble Inserting Text in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets-api, google-workspace

When I click in a column in Google Sheet to insert data, a blue box appears that doesn't sync with the google sheet column. Hence,  all the text is outside the intended box.
the columns of the google sheet are not syncing with the data entries.  Data entries
are crossing over into the other column (this is irrespective of  wrap around, options)